# Iterating through a column for cells starting with particular words | Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I am using my whole year's bank statement to learn Python data analysis.
I want to extract from one column cell that start with particular word
How will I search in a column for items that start with particular word?

Example:

```
STAPLES       00101683 WEST VIRGINIA AZ        12/29
STAPLES       00101683 ORANGE CA        12/26

ADOBE STOCK 408-536-6000 CA                  11/28
ADOBE CREATIVE CLOUD 408-536-6000 CA         11/27

Zelle payment to Mr. ABCD xxx85000860
Zelle payment to gohjjpkp tttt85137494040
```

How will I search for these items in one excel column?

Comment: What do you want to search?

Comment: please provide an example of the source. ie. is the file an excel file `xlsx` or a `csv` ? Please also provde and example of what you want to look for and what you want the result to be.  This is a useful guide for asking questions:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example